# Should we encourage tagging according to the appropriate field of law?

Tags: discussion, tags

Several times already I've edited questions to tag a specific field of law, since I thought this helped make them clearer (such as labor-law, or criminal-law). Is this something we should actually be striving for? Or is the jurisdiction of a question along with the topic (say, radio) clear enough without bothering to add the relevant field of law (almost) every time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tagging questions with only the jurisdiction and some vague topic (like 'radio') is *not* a great way to organize your content.

Since the [**areas of legal practice**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_areas_of_law) are relatively well-established specialties that folks are likely to study and practices, tagging the questions as such sounds like a great idea.

Since the correct field-tag isn't necessarily obvious when someone is *asking* a question, you will likely have to help these folks add the correct tags until the practice catches on.

Comment: To expand - the formal definition of a good tag includes "someone is likely to be an expert in the {tag}". This is why the second paragraph is especially fitting.

Comment: One downside is that you might exclude responses from people with filters set. A non-legal person rarely knows what areas of law a question will impact.